# Extract Second Level Domain from URL with RegEx

Tags: regex, url, tld

**Update.** Assume, that domain name are the last two items of the host name, except the second is **co** or **com**, in which case, domain name are the last three items. If there is just one item -> it is the domain name.

That the minimum cases to handle:

```
http://google.com          -> google.com
http://www.google.com      -> google.com
http://abc.cde.google.com  -> google.com
http://google.co.uk        -> google.co.uk
http://www.google.com.au   -> google.com.au
http://www.mysite.info     -> mysite.info
http://www.mysite.business -> mysite.business
http://localhost           -> localhost
```

**Regex sandbox for this question**

Here are the tests and some starting regexp https://regex101.com/r/AyuW88/3

**As a bonus,** a few more cases (but I would be already very happy if regex works just with the former cases)

```
http://google.com:8080      -> google.com
http://www.google.com?q=abc -> google.com
http://www.google.com/smth  -> google.com
```

Comment: Alexei, I think that you have a problem, I think it's not possible for a simple regex to  differentiate between a domain like google.co.uk (that you want) and a domain like cde.google.com (where you want only google.com) without some domain knowledge (no pun intended)

Comment: I agree. The example regex assumes, that ending xx(x).yy(y) identifies tlds like co.uk, com.au etc. But there are of course "normal" 2 and 3 letters domains, like ya.ru and gmx.de. I think I update the my question to make it solvable. Thanks for your remark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for your simple cases:

```
 r'([^\/\.]+\.(com|co)\.\w+|[^\/\.]+.\w+)$'
```

Captured in group 1.  Your assumption "except the second is co or com" is hardcoded in the regex. Also, there is a typo on the line:

```
http://www.google.com.au   -> google.com.ua
```

Should be "google.com.au"

Comment: This is not how second-level domains work and this regex is easily broken. There are something like 1500 combinations of sublevel domains and I've yet to find a regex capable of distinguishing between a domain with a second-level domain and a domain with multiple sub domains. This is an incredibly difficult regex to write considering the vast amount of second-level domains you'd have to account for (assuming you wanted one that accounted for all of them).

Answer (score -1):

This regex should address your use case.

Regex: `(?<=http(s)?:\/\/).*`

**Explanation:**
`(?<=http(s)?:\/\/)`: Positive lookback, to see if word is http or https.
`.*`: Will capture everything after that.

Link: https://regex101.com/r/fX1fI5/130

*Hope this helps.*